# Sending new data do child component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to make reusable countdown timer component in Angular.

When countdown is finished I get event from child.
Then I want to be able give new time to countdown, but I dont know how to achive this. How can I pass new value to the same child component?

Parent html:

```
<app-counter [time]="10" (onFinish)="onFinish($event)"></app-counter>
```

Child:

```
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('time') time: number; 
  @Output() onFinish = new EventEmitter(); 

  private interval;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countdown();
  }

  countdown() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.time--;
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.stop();
        this.onFinish.emit();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stop();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngOnChanges lifecycle hook allow you to track the changes of the @Input properties. You could do something like this in your parent component:

```
onFinish(e) {
    this.timer = 10;
}
```

In your child you can do:

```
ngOnChanges() {
    this.countdown();
}
```

And in the template simply bind the time property in child to the timer property in parent:

```
<app-counter [time]="timer" (onFinish)="onFinish($event)"></app-counter>
```

P.S. Since you are working with Angular I would strongly recommend you to use RxJS for implementing timers rather than setInterval.

**UPDATE**

You can gain complete control over the child from the parent with the @ViewChild decorator. You can do:

```
export class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChild('counter') private counter: CounterComponent;

    // ...
    onFinish(e) {
        this.counter.countdown() // calling the method of the child from parent
    //...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to pass the same value after finished countdown?

Comment: You can pass any value you want to from the parent.

Comment: But then it does not detect changes.

Comment: When the parent property bound to child through @Input changes it should trigger the ngOnChanges hook in child automatically.

Comment: Yeah, but If parent pass 10 second then on finish, child emit event and then parent want to pass again 10 seconds. But there is no change so ngOnChanges dont see any changes :/